# Unable to start a console in heroku's bamboo stack - ruby 1.8.7, toolbelt 2.39.4

Tags: ruby, heroku, console

I execute this:

```
$ /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku version
heroku-toolbelt/2.39.4 (i686-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.8.7

$ rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p299
Using /Users/jose/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p299

$ /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku run script/rails console -a app
Running script/rails console attached to terminal... up, run.8571
/usr/bin/env: ruby1.8: No such file or directory
```

I'm not able to start a rails console on my production environment. What am I doing wrong? I have done it this way many times for years...., although this project is not very active and I've not done it since 3 months ago or so.

Thank you four your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested:

I had to change my script/rails file in my project. I don't know the reason but it has this line at the beginning:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.8
```

I changed it to

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and everything worked fine after pushing the changes to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a couple of things:

When  you do

```
rvm use ruby-1.8.7-p299
```

you are doing that locally, for the environment on your own computer using RVM (Ruby Version Manager).

When you do

```
 /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku run script/rails console -a app
```

perhaps you should be doing something more like:

```
heroku run rails console
```

as detailed at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3

Final comment is that you really should be getting on Ruby 1.9+ anyway and the switch is usually relatively painless (less painful that rails versions for sure).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I execute rvm in the question just to show that I'm using ruby 1.8.7. When I execute /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku is to assure that I'm using the heroku toolbelt, not the old heroku gem. The final comment is that I've been executing this command `heroku run script/rails console -a app` for years, and now that I needed to connect again after 3 months, I'm unable to connect, although my environment is basically the same :(